# django return link username in model

Tags: django, django-models

I know it's not true what's in the code
how i can return the usernames that the api is linked to

To view in the admin page

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class api(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"api key for: {self.user.username}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8001379/6842203

Comment: Something is wrong in your implementation, you won't be able to access `self.user.username` since it's a M2M field and there won't necessary be a single user instance matching your api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"api key for: {[user.username for user in self.user.all()]}"
```

This returns all the usernames related to the ManytoManyField in a list.

eg: If you have two users with usernames austin and aron, It'll return as **"api key for: ['austin', 'aron']"**

ManytoManyField does not contain a single object instance, hence you cannot use self.user.username.

Answer (score 0):

If it's meant to be a ManyToManyField (i.e. you can assign multiple users to one API-key) Then you can use this:

```
def __str__(self):
    usernames = ', '.join(user.username for user in self.users.all())
    return f"api key for: {usernames}"
```